# How to show event calendar with active links and event details underneath

Tags: 7, views, datetime

I wanna show a page with calendar by month and all the upcoming events that fall within that month underneath.

So, on the page, I'd have this calendar that shows the current month:

Underneath I want the details of the events that fall in this month.

Any idea which module I should use and how can I achieve that in Drupal 7?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have not tried this, but i think it will work, with calendar module enebled, go to month view, add a block view and build your underneath view, then add this block view as a footer (middle column in views ui) in your month view (Global: View area), then pass arguments in settings to be the same as your month view.

Comment: Thank you. Do you think I can have some kind of tutorial for this?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6Tr1sZBFRWU, learn calendar module, then add block view as a footer, its easy.